# Persistent errors with certificate hash algorithm proposals on IKEv2 VPN after receiving updates on Windows 11 22H2

Tags: networking, vpn, security, windows-11

I have been dealing with VPN errors that persist across new OS installs and so seem to have to do with Windows 11 updates the PC is receiving. It is an IKEv2-only VPN with the native Windows client. Upon a new Windows 11 Pro installation from bootable media made with the Microsoft tool, the VPN works properly. However, eventually it will always start failing to connect after the computer has been updated. According to the server logs this is because, for unknown reasons, Windows begins ignoring the VPN connection configuration or becomes unable to use the proper algorithm to verify the RSA root certificate in the certificate store which serves as the authentication for this VPN. The connection is always set to use SHA256 for the hash using PowerShell, and the Windows certificate store reports the same as the signature hash algorithm for the root certificate. When the error starts, though, Windows offers `3072-bit RSA PKCS1 with SHA1` to the server, which is rejected as insecure and disabled server-side.

I have tried several methods attempting to force the PC to never use SHA1 in negotiations, including:

- Using the `Disable-TlsCipherSuite` cmdlet in PowerShell to disable all sets
  using SHA1 hash
- Disabling SHA1 in the registry entries for Schannel (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA\Enabled=0`)
- Adding an IPsec main mode policy with PowerShell to the active store with the default hardcoded one specifying SHA1 that the VPN client seems to be falling back to
- Overriding TLS cipher suite order with Group Policy
- Hardening RemoteAccess settings with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\Parameters\NegotiateDH2048_AES256=1` (This generally gives a different error message than the one I'm getting, "policy match error" whereas mine is "error processing payload")
- Various resets and cache clearing of network, winsock, etc. with `netsh`
- Forcing re-initialization of the WAN Miniport adapters by uninstalling them with Device Manager
  - Adding `AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule=2` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\PolicyAgent` (though this may only affect L2TP/IPsec connections, and my server is not behind a NAT)

I thought this may have to do with the implementation of the new Credential Guard in Windows update, as I get the same Security Center messages about Credential Guard and event log warnings mentioning incorrectly signed LSA packages as those mentioned by Microsoft as bugs. I attempted to disable Credential Guard as suggested by adding `LsaCfgFlags` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard` (Microsoft's own suggestion, they seem to half admit in documentation CG may break things), but this had no effect and Security Center is reporting Credential Guard as still enabled. Microsoft also suggests disabling Virtualization Based Security entirely, though I really have no desire to do this completely for security reasons.

Any assistance would be much appreciated, as I do not wish to enable SHA1 as an accepted cipher on the server-side, given that it is very old, vulnerable to collision attacks, and undergone deprecation by many including Microsoft themselves. I prefer the speed and ease of the native VPN client, but will have to do the work of changing over to a third-party VPN solution if I can't figure this out. I posted this on Microsoft Learn Q&A and it was deleted in minutes for "violating Community Guidelines." They don't seem to share what those are. So I brought this really controversial tirade over here. All jokes aside, I do happen to find a VPN client randomly downgrading its proposals with no warning pretty serious myself. I still can't get my Windows Security to stop saying Credential Guard is on with Group Policy or the registry, and as this cycle has repeated a few times now, I am half-convinced Microsoft is breaking their own VPN client with all this virtualization security they are rolling out.